# is #include <limits> cross platform?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I were to do:

```
int imin = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

will I get the same value regardless of which compiler/OS, or are these values implementation dependent?

If they are compiler/os dependent, would using my own constants:

```
  static unsigned short MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT = 65535;
  static uint64_t MAX_UNSIGNED_64LONG = 18446744073709551615u;
```

cause issues; say on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: You may want to consider using the types and limit macros for fixed-width types in `stdint.h`.

Comment: They are cross platform in the sense that "they are always the maximum and minimum values that can be stored in an `int`". Any variation you see in their values is from the fact that `int` has implementation-defined aspects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These values are implementation dependent (See the documentation for `std::numeric_limits` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max#Return_value).) However, they are guaranteed by the standard be able to represent values up to a certain value (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types) for specific details.)

Using your own constants should never cause issues as long as the constants fall within the permitted representable values for that type. In your example the value for `MAX_UNSIGNED_SHORT` and `MAX_UNSIGNED_64LONG` both fall within the values for their respective types. They should be fine.

On another note, if you use [fixed width integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) types the result of `std::numeric_limits::max` should remain the same across implementations for the specfic type. (e.g `std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()` will return the same value across platforms, and `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` will return the same value across platforms, but `std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() != std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`.)
However, as @rci pointed out, fixed width types are optional according to the standard, therefore they aren't guaranteed to be present in all implementations.

Comment: Two points. First, with unsigned integers, wrap around operations are well defined. So having using maximums or minimums that differ from the true values can actually break program logic. Second, you wrote "even if the underlying type does not". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()` will return the same value on every platform *in which `uint16_t` is defined*. It's an optional type, see 18.4.1. `uint_least16_t` is a required type, but it doesn't have a consistent `max` value. The "underlying type" for `uint16_t` has 16 bits. If there is no such type, `uint16_t` will not exist.

Comment: @NirFriedman By that I meant whichever type is used for the fixed width type internally. For example `uint16_t` could be represented using a short internally, but it is also allowed to be be an `int` and that could change between implementations. Even so, I have removed that part from the answer to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 2):

They are implementation dependent, int is defined by the standard as being at least as long as short, as well as having at least sixteen bits. Everything else is at the discretion of the implementation. Nowadays, you'll generally see 32 bits for integer.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

It's hard to say whether it would cause issues, it depends on the details. You could safely use the values for 16 bits. It's generally not a good idea to hand define your own limits.

Honestly, the best thing to do is #include cstdint and simply use the fixed size types, e.g. int32_t, which have to be a specific size.

Comment: There is no requirement that int be (at least) the size of a short, nor a requirement that it be at least 16 bits.   The standard specifies the (minimum) ranges the types must be able to represent.   Those ranges correspond to 16 logical bits, or to 16 physical bits on binary hardware  (implemented using transistors).  However, there is nothing in the standards that prevent implementation on a non-binary machine.

Comment: @Peter: I'm not going to get into non-binary machines. For implementations of broad interest, signed-ness + size directly translates to an integer range. More interestingly though you write that there is no requirement that an int be at least the size of a short. Is this a nitpick, or are you genuinely claiming that there is no requirement that the range of values of an int be a superset of char? If the latter, can you provide a source?

Comment: @Peter: Most of those claims are not correct. 3.9.1/2 guarantees that int is at least as long as short int. 3.9.1/7 specifies binary ("The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system".)